# Bootstrap applying different class on different device

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have this simplified code :

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 text-right">
        <h1>
            Left column
        </h1>       
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 text-right">
        <h1>
            Right column
        </h1>       
    </div>
</div>
```

my problem is : how to remove or change that `text-right` class into different class (for example : text-left) when visible on smaller device?

but keep that `text-right` when user open from medium device (MD).

thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily create your own custom class with media queries (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries for reference) to describe this behaviour:

```
@media (max-width: 320px) {
    .conditional-text-align {
        text-align: left;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 321px) {
     .conditional-text-align {
        text-align: right;
    }
}
```

Then you just have to switch classes in your HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 conditional-text-align">
        <h1>
            Left column
        </h1>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 conditional-text-align">
        <h1>
            Right column
        </h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Adjust the `max-width` and `min-width` values to your liking.